# Using getElementsByClassName seems to get too many elements

Tags: javascript, html

Running the following code and pressing the button should log to the console window 2 elements, the elements with the `class="test1"`, the button and the `p` element. And `console.log(el.length)` is `2`. BUT what logs to console is this:

```
[p#div1.test1, 
 button#btn.test1, 
 div1: p#div1.test1, 
 btn: button#btn.test1]
```

which looks like `4` elements not `2`.

What is happening here?

```
<html>
<body>
<p class="test1" id="div1">test1</p>
<button id="btn" onclick="getElements()" class="test1">Get Element List</button>
<script>
function getElements()
{
    var txt = document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML;

    var el = document.getElementsByClassName(txt);
    if (el) {
        console.log(el); 
        console.log(el.length); 
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You seem too excited about the "normalities" of `console.log`. everything is perfectly ok and works as should. the output is correct. what is the real problem here besides misunderstanding the log?

Comment: My question probably should have been: why are there four elements (i.e., separated by commas) in console.log(el)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because it's a HTML Collection that is returned, which is array like, but not an array. If you change your code to

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName(txt);
if (el) {
    console.log(Array.from(el)); 
    console.log(el.length); 
}
```

which will turn the collection into an array, you will see the real array, containing only 2 items.

```
[p#div1.test1, button#btn.test1]
0: p#div1.test1
1: button#btn.test1
length: 2
```

A HTML Collection exposes two methods

```
HTMLCollection.item()
HTMLCollection.namedItem()
```

That's why it seems like it were double the amount of entries, though it's not.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is that `getElementsByClassName` doesn't return an array, but an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection).

[`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) has the information directly as properties "by both name and index", so that is why it looks like it has 4 members.